Is it correct to follow argmax with an inequality? $\arg \max_{x}\{f(x)<g\}$
In some papers, I saw a formula like this：$\arg \max_{x}\{f(x)<10\}$. I guess the author here wants to express that when $f(x)<10$, the largest of all $x$. This is different from the definition of $argmax$ I've seen before.
Is this correct? If I want to express the maximum value of $x$ under certain conditions (like $f(x)<10$), is there a better way?

Yes, it is correct. You can write $\arg \max\limits_{x \in A} \{f(x) < 10\}$ as:
$$\max{\{ x \in A \ : \ f(x) < 10 \}} \ ,$$
where $A$ is your domain.
